# select only updating elements with d3.js

Tags: d3.js

With a `d3.js` `join` Is there a way to select only the 'updating' elements separately from the 'entering' elements?

```
updateAndEnter = d3.selectAll('element').data(data);

entering = updateAndEnter.enter();

exiting = updateAndEnter.exit();

updatingOnly = ??;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the selection just after the data join contains the 'update only' elements. After appending to the enter() selection, it will be expanded to include the entering elements as well.

See [General Update Pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/3808218):

```
  // DATA JOIN
  // Join new data with old elements, if any.
  var text = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(data);

  // UPDATE
  // Update old elements as needed.
  text.attr("class", "update");

  // ENTER
  // Create new elements as needed.
  text.enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "enter")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * 32; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em");

  // ENTER + UPDATE
  // Appending to the enter selection expands the update selection to include
  // entering elements; so, operations on the update selection after appending to
  // the enter selection will apply to both entering and updating nodes.
  text.text(function(d) { return d; });

  // EXIT
  // Remove old elements as needed.
  text.exit().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

it's my pleasure

For me ( too ) this is a little bit confusing : it seems that the only available set is actually ENTER+UPDATE ( blended together ) and EXIT.

But what if i want to work or at least identify only updated elements?
I wrote a very simple function ( that follows, simply put wrap it in a script tag at the end of a basic html page ) showing this simple dilemma : how do I highlight updated elements ? Only ENTER and EXIT seem to react "correctly"

To test it, just type in chrome console :

```
manage_p(['append','a few','paragraph'])
manage_p(['append','a few','new','paragraph'])
manage_p(['append','paragraphs'])
```

I can get green or red highlighting, i can't get white

Maybe we're missing D3Js specs?

Best regards,
 Fabrizio

```
function join_p(dataSet) {

var el = d3.select('body');
var join = el
.selectAll('p')
.data(dataSet);

join.enter().append('p').style('background-color','white');

join.style('background-color','green').text(function(d) { return d; });

join.exit().text('eliminato').style('background-color','red');
}
```